# Cassandra : Cannot replace address with a node that is already bootstrapped

Tags: cassandra

One of the existing nodes in a 5 node Cassandra (3.9) cluster fails to come up.

I noticed the node to be down and tried to restart using the command

> service cassandra restart

But the node fails to come and I see the below exception in `system.log`

> ERROR [main] 2017-04-14 10:03:49,959 CassandraDaemon.java:747 -
>   Exception encountered during startup java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Cannot replace address with a node that is already bootstrapped
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:752)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:648)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:548)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:385)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9] WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook]
>   2017-04-14 10:03:49,963 Gossiper.java:1508 - No local state or state
>   is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
>   WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-04-14 10:51:49,539
>   Gossiper.java:1508 - No local state or state is in silent shutdown,
>   not announcing shutdown

Thanks

Comment: The exception message is different. I guess the version of cassandra are different.
And I am not trying to replace a dead node. i am just trying bring up an existing node.

Comment: Have you had a look at you `cassandra-env.sh` it looks like there is an replace address configured there?

Comment: You are right. Somebody from Dev-ops had created an entry with this IP in cassandra-env.sh. After i removed it, the node came up successfully. You saved my day. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: :) you also made my day ... I like helping ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this guide, basically you have a dead node in the cluster, happens all the time ;)

https://blog.alteroot.org/articles/2014-03-12/replace-a-dead-node-in-cassandra.html

Plus some additional descriptions:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7356

Plus check that you also remove the address from:
`/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`

Comment: how to ensure or confidently say that the node is dead ? just that it doesn't come up is sufficient ? I am just trying to bring up an existing node here. not replacing with new node.

Comment: Nodes can join the cluster after quite some time actually. I guess it's not sufficient if it just doesn't come up. It's more a case when instance is gone like on AWS or something. Could it happen that another node is having this node's ip address. Can you get me nodetool status from other nodes? plus the ip address of the problematic node